# Sumar numeros de un array

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente codigo

```js
let a= [1,2,3,4]
let b= [5,6,7,8]
let c= [9,10,11,12]

let sumar= a+b+c

console.log(sumar)
```

Y necesito sumarlos todos, por decir:  1+2+3+4+5+6+.. etc. El caso es que pueden ser mas de 3 arrays (Coloque 3 para el ejemplo) por lo cual no me sirve utilizar la funcion `concat()`

El probado colocar

```js
let sumar = a+b+c
```

Pero me devuelve `1,2,3,45,6..` tipo Stirng y no puedo usar un foreach o map, porque no me lo devuelve como arreglo. Y si transformo la variable sumar (String) a Arreglo usando `let arreglo = [...d]` Me agrega las comas.

Como se puede resolver?

Answer (score 1):

```
let a= [1,2,3,4]
let b= [5,6,7,8]
let c= [9,10,11,12]

let todosJuntos = [...a,...b,...c]

todosJuntos.reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0)
```

Primero uno todos los elementos con spread operator en un único array, luego sumo todos los elementos del array resultante con reduce.
El todosJuntos.reduce podrías depositarlo en una variable para usar el resultado o poner directamente el código donde lo necesites.

Depositar en una variable para usarlo luego me refiero a algo ej:

```
const resultado = todosJuntos.reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0)
```

Y luego utilizarlo para mostrar o setear algo, ej:

```
console.log(resultado)
```

---

Agrego otra forma basada en parametros rest..

```
const sumar = (...args) => {
let todosJuntos = []
for(arg of args){
todosJuntos = [...todosJuntos, ...arg]
}
return todosJuntos.reduce((prev, current)=>prev + current, 0)   
}

sumar([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12])
```

Eliminé el primer reduce que lo único que hace es poner en el current del primer reduce el array que se está recorriendo, luego el segundo hace la suma de cada uno de sus elementos, y este proceso se repite tantas veces como arrays existan en args. En este ejemplo, recorro args con un forof y por cada array voy armando el array todosJuntos con todos los valores de todos los arrays, finalmente retorno el resultado de un único reduce sobre el array todosJuntos.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, solo agregaría el código en vez del comentario final para hacerlo más práctico.

Comment: Lo tendré presente, agregué un ejemplo depositado en una variable y usando la variable, también otro ejemplo con parámetros rest, con un solo reduce, el reduce concatenado puede ser un poco confuso. Favor si considerás que es una solución a tu planteo, darle a la respuesta en el visto al costado. Para que otros la puedan tomar como correcta y aprovechar. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Si bien las respuestas que te han proporcionado funcionan, el tema es que no solucionan uno de los problemas principales, el cuál es que puede ser uno, dos, tres, cuatro, n cantidad de arrays, lo cual con las soluciones ya propuestas tendrías que modificar el código una y otra vez. Para esto puedes apoyarte de los [parámetros rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

> La sintaxis de los parámetros rest nos permiten representar un número indefinido de argumentos como un array.

De hecho si miras el ejemplo que muestran para los parámetros rest, podrás darte cuenta de que la solución se aproxima mucho a lo que quieres lograr, con la excepción de que en tu problema, cada elemento no es un número, si no que es otro array. Por lo cual basta con anidar otro [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) para realizar la suma, y agregar la inicialización en 0. Con esto sumarás cada elemento de cada array.

```js
const sumar = (...args) => {
  return args.reduce((prev, current) => {
    return prev + current.reduce((prev, current) => {
      return prev + current;
    }, 0);
  }, 0);
}

console.log(sumar([1], [2], [3]));
console.log(sumar([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]));
console.log(sumar([1, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]));
```

Claro, este ejemplo asume el *happy path*, así que tienes que asegurarte de verificar que los arrays no estén vacíos, contengan elementos válidos, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Ésta es otra opción, se deben añadir todos los array en uno sólo y recorrerlos como se muestra.

```
let a= [1,2,3,4]
let b= [5,6,7,8]
let c= [9,10,11,12]
let todosArrays = [a,b,c];
let total = 0;

todosArrays.forEach(function(el){
el.forEach(function(n){
  total += n;
})
});
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cos mo adición a las respuestas anteriores. Suponiendo que recibas x cantidad de arreglos con x cantidad de valores.

```js
let contenedorDeArreglos = []

//TL;DR
function generardorDeArreglos() {

  let numeroAlAzar = Math.round(Math.random() * 100) + 1
  let numeroDeArreglosAlAzar = Math.round(Math.random() * 20) + 1

  contenedorDeArreglos = [...new Array(numeroDeArreglosAlAzar).keys()]
    .map(x => [...new Array(numeroAlAzar).keys()].map(x => Math.round(Math.random() * 100)))

}

generardorDeArreglos()

//La magia esta en este contenedor de arreglos. 
let suma = contenedorDeArreglos.reduce((acumulador, nuevoValor) => {
  //Al valor acumulado, sumamos el total del arreglo actual. 
  return acumulador + nuevoValor.reduce((acu, nuevo) => acu + nuevo, 0)
}, 0)

console.log("Arreglos generados: ", contenedorDeArreglos.length)
console.log("Total de suma: ", suma)
console.log("Arreglos:")
contenedorDeArreglos.forEach(x => console.log(x))
```